# ResourceType (Skipping entry in package table) problem

Tags: android, resources, types

In debugger I am getting this warning (5 times):

> W 2265 ResourceType Skipping entry 0x106000d in package table 0 because it is not complex!

These warnings show every time an activity is brought to the front.
I have checked R.java and there is no resource with this address 0x106000d.

I have no idea what to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a warning. Unless you are experiencing concrete problems that you are certain relate to this, ignore it. The operating system logs all sorts of stuff that we as developers wind up simply having to ignore.

Answer (score 3):

The resource 0x106000d is the @android:color:white

This is bugging me too, because it warns me not only five times, but more than 50 times on more or less every activity.