# ResourceType Skipping Entry

Tags: android

I always get this strange warning. I want to solve this behaviour, and not ignore it.

LogCat:

```
04-25 18:12:32.145: W/ResourceType(459): Skipping entry 0x7f020001 in package table 0 because it is not complex!
```

I looked into my R.java class:

```
public static final int custom_button=0x7f020001;
```

Then i looked into styles.xml:

```
<item name="android:buttonStyle">@drawable/custom_button</item>
```

Custon_Button:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" >
        <shape>
            <solid
                android:color="#a276eb" />
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#6a3ab2" />
            <corners
                android:radius="3dp" />
            <padding
                android:left="10dp"
                android:top="10dp"
                android:right="10dp"
                android:bottom="10dp" />
        </shape>

    </item>
    <item>
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:startColor="#bf27c3"
                android:endColor="#6a3ab2"
                android:angle="270" />
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#6a3ab2" />
            <corners
                android:radius="4dp" />
            <padding
                android:left="10dp"
                android:top="10dp"
                android:right="10dp"
                android:bottom="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
 </selector>
```

I also use Greendroid in my Applikation.

Please help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ResourceType (Skipping entry in package table) problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4555721/resourcetype-skipping-entry-in-package-table-problem)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error when i set button attribute `style="@drawable\my_button"`.
I removed attirbute style and added `android:background="@drawable\my_button"` and warnings go away.